# react native firestore. 'array-contains' query not working with number value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Have a strange problem with [react-native-firebase](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6) library:

Steps:

Try to fetch data with the firestore:

```
await firestore().collection(collectionName)
                .where(ConversationModel.refs.employees, 'array-contains', '646').get();
```

where 646 - element in array

When I use an array of strings, this code works as expected

But when I set the number value (646) and try to fetch the array of numbers - this code returns empty result.

**Correct sample:**

> await firestore().collection(collectionName)
>                       .where(ConversationModel.refs.employees, 'array-contains', '646').get();

[image]

**Wrong sample:**

> await firestore().collection(collectionName)
>                       .where(ConversationModel.refs.employees, 'array-contains', 646).get();

[image]

**UPDATE:** Fixed in 6.1.0 https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/releases/v6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation found here   https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries says "You can use the array-contains operator to filter based on array **values**", I believe the key take away here is "values".

In the correct one you are using a **string** and in the wrong one you are using a **Integer**. It might then be that you have stored the values as **Text string** and not as **Integers**. Supported data types listed here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries are type-sensitive. If you want to get documents where the employees array contains **the number** `646`, you need to build a query that checks for that number. So something like:

```
await firestore().collection(collectionName)
            .where(ConversationModel.refs.employees, 'array-contains', 646).get();
```